# Implement multiple For loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to implement multiple for loop in batch like:

```
for x=1:10 
for y=x+1:10
//my code
end
end
```

My code is:

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (1,1,10) do (
 for /l %%y in (%%y+1,1,10) do (
  //my code
 )
)
```

However, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try changing `%%y+1,1,10` to `%%x+1,1,10`

Comment: @Dale - will not work , in batch you cannot do math in `for` definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reposting a solution but in a simpler script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%x in (1,1,10) do (
 set /a inner=%%x+1
    for /l %%y in (!inner!,1,10) do ( 
     echo %%x, %%y
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%x in (1;,;1step;,;10#=101) do (
 set /a inner=%%x+1

 @@echo ###%%x is from outer loop###

 for /l %%y in (,,,!inner!==1@==10times,9) do ( 

  @@echo -----%%y is from inner loop

 )
)
endlocal
```

**Simplified**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%x in (1;1;10) do (
 set /a inner=%%x+1

 echo - %%x is produced from outer loop

 for /l %%y in (!inner!;1;10) do ( 

 echo --- %%y is produced from inner loop

 )
)
```

Comment: No offense meant, but is there a reason you wrote it like that? That is incredibly difficult to read, and a newbie will have no hope to understand the points you have made.

Comment: @foxidrive - you're right - I should keep it more simple.Sometimes I tend to show a strange sense of humor...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (1,1,10) do (
 echo #LOOP [1] ITERATION [%%x]
 for /l %%y in (1,1,10) do (
 echo  ##LOOP [2] ITERATION [%%y]
 )
echo.
)
```

Comment: As far as I understand the question the OP want the inner loop to start from `%%x+1` ...